# bin/sh error and mekefile error 127 but i write bin/bash in my script?

Tags: c, bash, shell, makefile

I have this bash script which works (it print the output), but when i run the program, at the end there is the error /bin/sh not found, makefile error 127. I even didn't have bin/sh, i wrote bin/bash. `analisi.sh` is the script, this is the part of the makefile, `supermercato.PID` is where the PID of the thread supermercato is saved.

```
./run: 
cd src; \
(./supermercato & echo $$! > supermercato.PID) & \
cd ..; \
sleep 25s; \
kill -1 $$(cat src/supermercato.PID); \
chmod +x ./analisi.sh
./analisi.sh $$(cat src/supermercato.PID); \
```

this is the script `analisi.sh`, `test.log` is a file where the output is written

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f "test.log" ]; then
   while read line; do echo $line; done < test.log
else
   echo "$0:Errore" 1>&2
fi
```

Here is an example of the error (SIGHUP is part of the project). TEST is written on the log file named test.log which i read from the script.

```
Received SIGHUP
./analisi.sh $(cat src/supermercato.PID); \ 
******TEST******
/bin/sh: 1:  : not found
make: *** [Makefile:15: run] Error 127
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
./analisi.sh $$(cat src/supermercato.PID); \
```

has a *trailing space* (!) *and* the previous command ended in a semicolon, so BASH thinks you're trying to execute *two* commands: `./analisi.sh` followed by a command whose name consists of a single literal space character.

You can reproduce it in the terminal. Put a space after the backslash and hit Enter:

```
$ echo hey; \ 
hey
-bash:  : command not found
$
```

---

Also check the format of the error message:

```
$ wow
-bash: wow: command not found
```

So the format is:

```
<BASH>: <line number>: <command_name>: not found
```

In your case, it's

```
/bin/sh: 1:  : not found
```

Note how there are *two* spaces here: `:  :`.